# Sublime Text Key Commands

Tags: sublimetext2

I am trying to change how the key commands work for Sublime Text, specifically for Browse
SFTP:Browse Server. I see the key commands in the packages but still not sure how to go about this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to:

**Preferences -> Key Bindings (User)**

alternatively

**Preferences -> Package Settings ->  -> Key Bindings (User)**

In that file add:

```
[
    { "keys": ["ctrl+alt+k"], "command": "command_name"},
]
```

Take a look in **Preferences -> Key Bindings (Default)** to see how to set the keybinding to what you want.